Omitting address from \maketitle with template?
I am using this template to write a cover letter. I want to omit the addresses (ideally both mine and the employer).
I have commented out the \provideAdress line in the core tex file.

as well as removed any references in the Preamble.tex and Application.sty files

and I still can't compile with LuaLaTeX or or XeLaTeX.

Any help you can provide is appreciated.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment. Please include it as a code block and not as image.

Welcome to TeX.SE. As samcarter mentioned, please provide the code of the template, including the changes that you have made, in your question. A link might no longer work or provide different content over time, so to keep questions on the site useful for future visitors you have to make sure that the question is as self-contained as possible. Also please don't provide screenshots of code or errors, copy the text of the errors into your question instead.

do not show code as an image, always include it as text in a code block in the question.
